# Update deviceToken on Existing Parse iOS Installation

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I'm using Parse.com REST API to suscribe users for Push Notifications.

Sometimes DeviceToken changes, so I need to Update Parse Installation Object in order to update the DeviceToken.

According to the docs, it can be accomplished by doing a PUT Request: 
https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating

When executing the PUT request I have the following error result:

```
{"code":136,"error":"deviceToken may not be changed in this operation"}
```

Anyone else having the same Issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same issue. It looks like the problem is caused by another installation object having the same deviceToken. This happened to me when I switched between developer and production APNs certificates. 
To fix this, go to Parse and search Core for your deviceToken and delete it.

There was another issue I encountered where Parse did not have the deviceToken I was searching for but still would not let me update. In that case I had to delete the entire installation and re-create a new one.

Comment: I don't this solves the problem, because it's also forbidden to change the deviceToken even when installation is the only one with this deviceToken.

Comment: Right, that's why I said in some cases you need to delete the installation.